# Measurability of $X_{\tau-}$ if $X$ only has left-limits at the specific point $\tau$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $E$ be a topological space, $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space, $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:\infty]}$ be an $E$-valued progressively measurable process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $\tau$ be a stopping time on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with respect to the filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ generated by $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:\infty]}$.

Assuming that $X(\omega):[0,\infty]\to E$ has a left-limit $X_{\tau-}(\omega)$ at $\tau(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, are we able to show that $X_{\tau-}$ is measurable (at least with respect to $\mathcal A$)?

I only know how I can prove measurability under the stronger assumption that $X$ has left-limits at every point ...

BTW, we need Hausdorfness to ensure that the left-limit is unique, right?